# Spring Boot Java map Entity to DTO: array literal (strings) INSTEAD of array of objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, dto, modelmapper

sample get request: http://localhost:3000/contact/1

**What I got:**

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "First Name",
  "lastname": "Last Name",
  "emailaddresses": [
    {
      "emailaddress": "email@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "emailaddress": "email@g.c"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I want:**

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "First Name",
  "lastname": "Last Name",
  "emailaddresses": ["email@gmail.com","email@g.c"]
}
```

The code below:

PersonDto

```java
public class PersonDto {
    
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private List<EmailAddressDto> emailaddresses;
    //getters setters
}
```

EmailAddressDto

```java
public class EmailAddressDto {

    private String emailaddress;
    //getters and setters
}
```

the Service class

```java
public PersonDto getPerson(Long personId) { //this is the method inside the class

        Optional<PersonEntity> p = peopleRepository.findById(personId);
        var dto = modelMapper.map(p.get(), PersonDto.class);
        return dto;
}
```

I also have a `PersonEntity` class mapped one-to-many to an `EmailAddressesEntity` class.

I'm really new to spring/java - I couldn't figure out how to get the JSON structure I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just annotate `emailaddress` field of `EmailAddressDto` with `@JsonValue` and leave everything as is.

```
public class EmailAddressDto {
    
    @JsonValue
    private String emailaddress;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Using the above the output of a sample:

```
    PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto();
    personDto.setId(1L);
    personDto.setFirstname("John");
    personDto.setLastname("Doe");
    personDto.setEmailaddresses(Arrays.asList(new EmailAddressDto("john@doe.com"), new EmailAddressDto("foo@bar.com")));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(personDto);
    System.out.println(json);
```

is:

```
{"id":1,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","emailaddresses":["john@doe.com","foo@bar.com"]}
```

Comment: Definitely the best solution! And one more thing that I learned today ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your `PersonDto` that would be the easiest and cleanest way to do it.

```java
public class PersonDto {
    
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private List<String> emailaddresses;
    //getters setters
}
```

While mapping your entities you would need to map `EmailAddressesEntity` to a `String` representing it (`emailaddress`).

---

If this is not possible you will need a custom converter for `EmailAddressDto` as follows:

```java
public class ListEmailAddressDtoConverter extends StdConverter<List<EmailAddressDto>, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> convert(List<EmailAddressDto> emailAddresses) {
        return emailAddresses.stream().map(EmailAddressDto::getEmailaddress).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell Jackson to use it:

```java
public class PersonDto {
    
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    
    @JsonSerialize(converter = ListEmailAddressDtoConverter.class)
    private List<EmailAddressDto> emailaddresses;
    //getters setters
}
```

Comment: This also worked well. You were correct that I couldn't change the List type because it id being used by modelmapper to map automatically. I tried just changing the types and everything just becomes null.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use a List of Strings instead of a List of EmailAddressDto's.

Following reasons:

- Since you only have one attribute in your Dto, you can easily just directly use a List of Strings instead.
- You get the second JSON-Layout as a response to your GET-Request.

When using variant number 1 (with the List of EmailAddressDto), you will achieve a JSON-Response with multiple objects for your different E-Mail addresses.
Otherwise when you use variant number 2 (with the List of String), you will achieve a JSON-Response which looks like what you want to have.

So don't forget to change your entities aswell.

```
public class PersonDto {

private Long id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private List<String> emailAddresses;
//getters setters
}
```